# Symfony 3 : DateTime / date_time :

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, phpmyadmin

I am discovering Symfony.
I would like to insert in my database a date selected by the user in a DateType field present in a form.
This is my entity 'Suivi' with the date field :

```
class Suivi {

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var projet
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CDR\ProjetBundle\Entity\Projet", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $projet;

/**
 * @var date
 *@ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")
 */
private $date;
```

Here it's my form :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('Date', DateType::class)
            ->add('Moyen', ChoiceType::class, array('choices'  => array(
    'Téléphone' => "Téléphone",
    'Email' => "Email",
)))
            ->add('Contenu', TextareaType::class)              
            ->add('Enregistrer', SubmitType::class)
    ;
}
```

And this is the action in the controller file :

```
public function ajouterSuiviAction(Request $request, $id) {
    $suivi = new Suivi();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $projet = $em->getRepository("CDRProjetBundle:Projet")->find($id);
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(SuiviType::class, $suivi);
    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($suivi);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('cdr_projet_suivi');
    }

    return $this->render('CDRProjetBundle:Projet:ajoutsuivi.html.twig', array(
                'projet' => $projet,
                'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

When i submit my form, i have the following error : 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvote.png)

Someone have an idea ?

Comment: Could you also provide us the setDate function declaration in class Suivi?

Comment: Can you tell me the namespace of DateType class? There multiple implementation of DateType class!

Comment: It sounds like an issue with the type hinting in the signature of your your date setter

Comment: This is the setDate Function generated :
public function setDate(\date_time $date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
My setDate function was generated like this :

```
/**
 * Set date
 *
 * @param \date_time $date
 *
 * @return Suivi
 */
public function setDate(\date_time $date)
{
    $this->date = $date;

    return $this;
}
```

It's better like that :

```
/**
 * Set date
 *
 * @param \DateTime $date
 *
 * @return Suivi
 */
public function setDate(\DateTime $date)
{
    $this->date = $date;

    return $this;
}
```